# Proof for the derivative of the determinant of a matrix

Tags: matrix-analysis

I was looking for theorems that might be helpful in order for some proofs that I have and I came across the following one:

$$\frac{d}{dt} [\det A(t)]=\det A(t) \cdot \operatorname*{tr}[A^{-1}(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt} A(t)]$$

where $A(t)$ is a matrix with a variable $t$.

The problem is that I have neither a reliable source for this theorem nor am I able to prove it.

Did anyone come across the aforementioned equation or is able to prove it?

Comment: Have you even tried searching for it? If I write "derivative determinant" on Google I am showered with relevant results, even on a fresh profile.

Comment: This question really belongs to math.SE and I'm sure even there it's been asked a few times already! Voting to close.

Comment: Actually this question was indeed trivial and the answer was wikipedia-like, but I couldn't find any reference in my mother language and apparently googled the wrong words. I am sorry :/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just Jacobi's formula in the case of $A$ invertible.

Most books with any matrix theory in it should have a proof. Even wikipedia has [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Derivation).

Answer (score 35):

Another way to obtain the formula is to first consider the derivative of the determinant at the identity:
$$
 \frac{d}{dt} \det (I + t M) = \operatorname{tr} M.
$$

Next, one has 
$$
\begin{split}
   \frac{d}{dt} \det A (t)
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\det \bigl(A (t + h)\bigr) - \det A (t)}{h}\\
&=\det A (t) \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\det \bigl(A (t)^{-1} A (t + h)\bigr) - 1}{h}\\
&=\det A (t) \operatorname{tr} \Bigl(A (t)^{-1}\frac{d A}{dt} (t) \Bigr).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: It’s essentially an application of the chain rule.